# Cannot catch Kafka TopicExistsException

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have written a program which creates Kafka topics upon startup with AdminClient. If a topic exists, a TopicExistsException is thrown. However I am not able to catch it. Related code:

```
try {
    CreateTopicsResult result = adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(new NewTopic(topic, 2, (short) 1)));
    result.all().get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TopicExistsException e){
    log.info("topic exists: {}", topic);
} catch ( InterruptedException | TimeoutException | ExecutionException e){
    log.error("Topic create failed with: {}", e.getMessage());
}
```

The expected behavior would be that the first catch is executed, but based on the logs this is not what happens:

```
2020-12-01 13:18:56,462 ERROR [restartedMain] com.mypackage.KafkaService@lambda$configureTopics$0:75 - Topic create failed with: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'MEASUREMENT_TEST' already exists.
```

My imports are for the exceptions:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;
```

Any suggestion? Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the topic exists exception is getting wrapped in the `ExecutionException` that gets thrown when the `KafkaFuture` completes.

You can see this by logging the full stack trace, not just the `getMessage()` part:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'hello' already exists.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:262) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'hello' already exists.
```

So if you want to catch the `TopicExistsException`, you've got to do something like:

```
try {
    CreateTopicsResult result = adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(new NewTopic(topic, 2, (short) 1)));
    result.all().get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (ExecutionException e){
    if(e.getCause() != null && e.getCause() instanceof TopicExistsException) {
        log.info("topic exists: {}", topic);
    } else {
        log.error("Topic create failed with: {}", e);
    }
} catch ( InterruptedException | TimeoutException){
    log.error("Topic create failed with: {}", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, now it works with your solution!